# Hide multiple product attributes on woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I would like to hide a second attribute on the woocommerce product page.
It works great with this code for one attribute:

```
function my_attribute_hider ( $attributes ) {
if ( isset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] ) ){
    unset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] );
}
return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_product_attributes', 'my_attribute_hider' );
```

How to add a second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use this function for two product attribute, try the following:

```
function my_attribute_hider ( $attributes ) {
    if ( isset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] ) ){
        unset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name2'] ) ){
        unset( $attributes['pa_attribute-name2'] );
    }
    return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_product_attributes', 'my_attribute_hider' );
```

It should work.

Comment: LoicTheAztec I wanted to thank you because indeed it works
Thanks Eric